# RedisCache.putIfAbsent is not setting the TTL on the element

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using `RedisCache.putIfAbsent` operation of spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar to set the element value atomically along with the `ttl` value.

This is how I generate the Cache Manager instance

```
public CacheManager dsyncCacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager( redisTemplate() );
    redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(defaultExpireTimeSeconds);
    return redisCacheManager;
}
```

This is how I call the method

```
cache.putIfAbsent( key, value );
```

However, When I go and check the `ttl` of the given key in redis, the value returned is `-1` and not the expected `ttl` I used.

Comment: There's already an issue [DATAREDIS-542](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-542) open in the bug tracker.

Comment: @christoph-strobl : 
thank you for the quick reply. When can we expect this to be fixed?

Comment: we've recently checked the code and it seems the `EXPIRE` command is issued correctly. I saw you did not set a `keySerializer` which defaults to the   jdk serializer producing keys like `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bcache-key-1`. Which Redis version do you use? As of Redis 2.8 the `TTL` command returns -2 when called on a key that does not exist. Maybe you could add a failing testcase to [DATAREDIS-542](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-542).

Comment: we are using spring-data-redis-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar.
Redis version 2.8.19

Comment: Regarding keySerializer, are you saying key expiry for RedisCache.putIfAbsent() command will NOT work on default key serializer??

Comment: the `RedisSerializer` has no impact on the `EXIPIRE` command just on the key generated. it just happens sometimes that the CLI is used to check the `TTL`, and using `cache-key-1` instead of `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bcache-key-1` can be source of confusion. just wanted to check that.